# what are `switch` statements for?

Tags: language-agnostic, switch-statement

Switch statements: I know what they do - I use them so many times, as per convention normally when I want to do different stuff based on the value of an Enum, but now it just hit me: *Why are we using it?* **What was its original purpose?** I mean, this:

```
switch(myVar) {
    case Foo:
        doSomething();
        break;
    case Bar:
        doSomethingElse();
        break;
    default:
        justAnotherThing();
        break;
}
```

Has the exact same behaviour as:

```
if(myVar == Foo) {
    doSomething()
}else if(myVar == Bar) {
    doSomethingElse();
}else {
    justAnotherThing();
}
```

Plus `if`'s lets you make inequality comparisons (`>`, `<`, `!=`) if you need it. The only case that I may find a switch more useful is when you don't use the `break` statement inside: but this happens not too often and I find it terrible on code-quality.

I really can't find any benefit of using `switch` over `if`... So why was it defined for?

Comment: Now do the same `if-else if` chain with ten alternatives, or twenty, and you will find it's not very readable. Also, the compiler might be able to optimize the `switch` into a simple jump-table, instead of having to evaluate each condition until it finds a "match". And remember that in C-like languages (which you seem to use as base) cases *fall through* to the next `case` below if there's no `break`. That's much harder to do in an `if-else if` chain.

Comment: As for read-ability I think they are almost on par - as long as you keep a consistent identation and you're using `if-else if` on the case you'd use a `switch`, as `}else if(myVar == ` always takes the same space will make all posible values aligned and easy to read.

Comment: And in my question I did mention the fall-through behaviour by removing `break`, but this is terrible for readability: So you have cases that may or may not jump to the next one, and altering the order of cases would affect the behaviour. I only use this "trick" to make an `or` comparison into a switch, and try to avoid otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some languages allow inequality comparisons in `switch` statements as well, e.g. Visual Basic:

```
Select Case x
  Case < 5
    // ...
  Case 7
    // ...
  Case 10 To 15
    // ...
  Case Else
    // ...
End Select
```

Basically, yes, the `switch` can often be written as an `if`/`else if` ladder, with the distinction that `switch` compares *one* value against a number of comparison values, `if`/`else if` can do anything in every single branch. But even that isn't the case in all languages, e.g. in PowerShell a `switch` can do plenty of things that you usually have to use `if` for:

```
switch -Regex ($x) {
  '^\d+$' {'Number'}
}
```

or

```
switch ($x) {
  { $_ is [int] -or $_ is [double] } {'Number'}
  { $_ is [string] } {'Text'}
}
```

Generally, however, `switch` is easier to read for the common case of comparing a single value against a finite set of options. Furthermore, it enables the compiler to do certain optimizations which are harder to analyse on `if`/`else if`, such as using binary search to determine the correct case instead of linear search, or even using a jump table or arithmetic. E.g. the following switch

```
switch (x) {
  case 0:
    // Do something with 0
    break;
  case 1:
    // Do something with 1
    break;
  case 2:
    // Do something with 2
    break;
  ...
}
```

could be compiled into the equivalent of

```
Action[] actions = {
  () => { /* Do something with 0 */ },
  () => { /* Do something with 1 */ },
  () => { /* Do something with 2 */ },
  ...
};
if (x >=0 && x <= n) {
  actions[x]();
}
```

The simplicity and limitations of `switch` are helpful in this case for an optimizing compiler because there's much less to analyse to determine what the overall structure is trying to do.

There are other features (sometimes maybe of dubious value), such as [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device), or being able to fall through to other cases (or `goto` arbitrary other cases, which, e.g. C# allows).

You may just as well ask the question why we have `if` statements and loops instead of just using `goto`. Yes, structured programming constructs are, taken one by one, strictly inferior in what they can express, compared to the more general construct. But they are more readable, make the intent clearer, and tend to be safer and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

`switch` is a pretty low-level statement, in the sense that the code in the `case` statements is compiled into a continuous block of instructions in memory which is simply conditionally jumped into (depends on the language in question of course, modern high-level languages may behave quite different under the hood). That's also why you have the fall-through behaviour, once a starting address is determined simply all following instructions are executed unless broken out of.

So initially it was a very natural way to jump over or into a block of instructions. Many languages have adopted the `switch` statement, many likely due to familiarity, but many likely also because it *is* indeed rather readable for certain cases, e.g.:

```
switch (someComplicatedCalculation($foo, $bar)) {
    case CONSTANT_A:
        ...
    case CONSTANT_B:
        ...
    ...
}
```

That's a pretty succinct way to express this, especially if you're maybe also depending on the fall-through behaviour.

Of course, other languages have never adopted `switch`, e.g. Python, and require the use of `if..elif..else` instead. In the end you can write similar code using either language construct, it's up to you.